# exceptions in C++ vs exceptions in other languages

Tags: c++, exception

the idea I have about using exceptions  and `try {} catch {}` blocks is that those are used for error handling.
I was reading [Bjarne's Strostrup FAQ page](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.htm) section about exceptions and I came across this

> There are other uses of exceptions - popular in other languages - but
>   not idiomatic in C++ and deliberately not supported well by C++
>   implementations (those implementations are optimized based on the
>   assumption that exceptions are used for error handling).

What are other usages for exceptions in  other languages (C# or java for example)?

Comment: Your question is too broad to really be answerable. So (even though I disagree with current rules, and some of the most up-voted questions on SO were of this type) I've voted to close it. Still, as an example, one usage is to break out of a deep recursion when an final result has been obtained.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480146/difference-between-exception-handling-in-c-and-java

Comment: Even if exceptions are used more commonly in other languages, and not only for "exceptional" situations, it's almost always for error handling, just like in C++.

Comment: Some other languages use exceptions as a standard control flow mechanism for deep returns. BTW: C has `longjump`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, in the spirit of "ask for forgiveness, not permission", exceptions are frequently used as part as the normal control flow of the application. For instance, when looking up an element in a dictionary (think `std::unordered_map` in C++):

```
try:
  my_value = my_dict["the answer to life, the universe and everything"]
except KeyError:
  my_value = 42
```

In C++, this is not considered an "erroneous" situation; exceptions should only be used in interaction with "unpredictable" things like hardware devices and (to some degree) the operating system.

Comment: Also in the internal workings of the Python `for` loop.

Comment: Please remember that bad user input is mostly considered unexceptional.

Comment: I fail to see how this is different then the use in C++. The usage of exception in protocols such as the iterator protocol seems a *much* better match as Cheers pointed out.

Comment: In C++ the standard containers don't even throw exceptions, ever, so this pattern wouldn't even be possible in C++. They just return the default value of the container's value type and you'd use `.find()` and compare to `.end()` to check for presence _before_ accessing the element. Feel free to add another answer (or edit mine) for the other example.

Comment: @Bakuriu the difference is that in C++ throwing an exception is a very high overhead process, so you try to avoid it whenever possible. In Python it's optimized so that it's no different than any other flow control paradigm.

Comment: C++ containers can throw, though mostly on allocation failure. They just don*t force you to use checked indexing, which they support.

Comment: @Thomas I don't see the difference between the `KeyError` in your example and the, for example, `out_of_range` exception raised by a vector's `at` method. If you want to avoid the exception in python you can use `.get`. On the other hand the usage of exceptions in language protocols is a completely different usage that isn't found in C++.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Yes, `vector` has `at`, but to my knowledge `unordered_map` doesn't have such a thing. And even with `vector`, using `at` and catching the exception would be highly unidiomatic C++, while it's perfectly normal in Python.

Answer (score 0):

One other use is `InterrutedException` in java. It allows waiting on monitors or sleeping threads step out of `wait` or `sleep`.

Comment: Interrupting a busy thread is considered evil and there are many gotchas.

Comment: @Deduplicator You probably think if ´Thread.stop´ which is a hard stop with all kinds of problems and which is tehrefore deprecated. ´Thread.interrupt´ gracefully asks the thread to terminate, that's why it needs to step out of wait et.al. to handle the interrupt request.