# Exception model in Java, C++, Python

Tags: java, c++, python, exception, checked-exceptions

Hey I am wondering how does Java exceptions model differ that in C++ and Python?

I thought it was that only Java had checked exceptions, but from what I read Python also has checked exceptions?

Any thoughts would be great, Thanks

Comment: Yes Python supports exceptions handling.

Comment: I think Python's checked exceptions makes use of decorators to emulate Java's `throws` declaration. I don't think it's a built-in feature.

Comment: See: http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions **and** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838460/java-exception-vs-c-exceptions

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Exception handling != checked exceptions.

Comment: @WaleedKhan What "Python's checked exceptions"? I've never seen such a thing, is it in some obscure third-party library? Then that's not really comparable IMHO.

Comment: @delnan Yes technically two words are `!=` :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan What I'm saying is: Having exception handling in the language doesn't even begin to imply having checked exceptions (look up what it is; you seem to not know), so you can't say "Yes, there's exception handling" in response to a question about *checked exceptions*.

Comment: @delnan You have good understanding. I am just kind of user :) thanks good point.

Answer (score 3):

Python does *not* have checked exceptions. But it does have exception handling mechanics.. e.g.

```
def test():
    raise Exception()

try:
    test()
except Exception:
    print "bugger."

# but its totally legal to just call it, and let any uncaught exceptions propagate
test()
```

is entirely legal thanks to the design of the python virtual machine,

```
public static void TestMethod(){
    throw new Exception();
}
```

on the other hand running code that *could* throw an exception (that the compiler will detect) that is not explicitly checked in Java is totally illegal. It just can't be done thanks to the design of the JVM and the byte compiler.